# Getting certain elements from the parent of input tag

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an input and an onchange function as below

```
'<section class="cubeMain" style="transform: translate3d(0 , ' + valY+ 'px , ' + valZ + 'px) rotateY(20deg) rotateX(-10deg);">'+
                        '<div>' +
                        "<input type='number' style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 250px\"" +
                        " onchange='update( this.parentNode.parentNode ,this.value  , " + arrayNum + " , " + c + " , " + a + " , " + b + " )' value='" + matrices[arrayNum][c][a][b] + "' >" +
                        '</div>' +
                       
                        '<div>' +
                        "<input type='number' style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 250px\"" +
                        " onchange='update( this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll("+ div + ") ,this.value  , " + arrayNum + " , " + c + " , " + a + " , " + b + " )' value='" + matrices[arrayNum][c][a][b] + "' >" +
                        '</div>' ....
```

what I'm trying to do is in the onchange function, when a value is changed, I want to go back to the section (parentNode.parentNode) and then to all the other inputs inside the parent. (what I'm actually trying to do is change the value of all the inputs when one of them changes)

Now I tried `this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(" div") ....`  but I get an error doing this.
What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: I suggest you start with providing a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The above onchange function is neither valid HTML nor valid JavaScript.